# Twitter created_at convert epoch time in python

Tags: python, twitter

I have this date from Twitter:

```
created_at = "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012"
```

I want to convert it to a time using something like:

```
time.mktime(created_at)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a 9-item sequence, not a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the incoming string to a Python time tuple using [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) before you can do anything with it.

This code will take the input string, convert it to a tuple and then converts that to a Unix-epoch time float using [`time.mktime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime):

```
import time
created_at = "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012"
print time.mktime(time.strptime(created_at,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"))
```

Comment: how can i change created_at timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't if it too late, use [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) package instead could *fewer imports and a lot less code*.

```
pip install arrow
```

Then:

```
>>> arrow.Arrow.strptime("Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
<Arrow [2012-08-29T17:00:58+00:00]>
>>> arrow.Arrow.strptime("Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y").timestamp
1346259658
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of [`time.mktime`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_mktime.htm)

It requires [`struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time), or you can alternatively represent it using a 9-tuple.

The required entries are:

1. Year
2. Month
3. Date
4. Hour
5. Minute
6. Second
7. Day in week
8. Day in year
9. Daylight Savings Time

This is not the function you need, however. It seems that you want to use [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) instead.

According to the documentation:

```
Parse a string representing a time according to a format.
The return value is a struct_time as returned by gmtime() or localtime().

>>> import time
>>> time.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")   
time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0,
                 tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)
```

So, you can do:

```
time.strptime(created_at)
```

Comment: can you convert "created_at" variable to epoch an exaple ?

Comment: I guess I'm too late, haha